# BeautifulSoup cannot read hypens in text?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape imdb.com with BeautifulSoup in Python, but there are some html tag that contains hypens '-' in its text, so system could not read it.
The page I was trying to scrape: [click here](https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=documentary)

I'm trying to extract "TV-MA" from tag below

```
<span class="certificate">TV-MA</span>
```

So, I will crawl using code like this :

```
item.find("span",{"class": "certificate"}).text
```

But, **the code above will return NoneType object error**. So that means, the span tag was not detected when I tried to ".find" the html tag. In the original html file, the span wasn't there as well (I knew this because I've tried to print the html code). **But again, when I tried to inspect element of the page, the span tag was there...**

I've tried crawling with other text that contain "-" with the same span, such as:

```
<span class="certificate">PG-13</span>
```

And the crawl code I've used above will work (which means it will return: "PG-13"). So I don't think the problem is with the code.

Comment: Not able to reproduce the issue, print the ``html`` content & see if the span tag exists in the response.

Comment: @sushanth Hi, thanks for the response. I've edited my post for this

Comment: "In the original html file, the span wasn't there as well", so it makes sense that you wouldn't find it right? There is no span tag to be found, unless I'm missing something here

Comment: @shayaan Yes that's true, I've edited my post again to show which page I was trying to crawl. When I tried to inspect element the page, the span tag was there, but if it's printed, the span tag was gone.

Comment: I think the certificate is converted to some values like `TV-MA` to 18 or `TV-G` to 7

Comment: Most probably, the missing parts are generated using some script. You see them in a browser, because it have run the scripts, but the tags don't exist in the source HTML. In this case you need Selenium.

Comment: The conversion to 18 I think is based on region/country.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=documentary')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find("span",{"class": "certificate"}).text
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
TV-MA
```